# How to multiply a dataframe's column by a log using julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe. I want to multiply column "b" by a "log" and then replace NaN by 0s.

How can I do that in Julia?
I am checking this: [DataFrames.jl](http://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/v0.17.0/lib/functions.html#DataFrames.dropmissing)
But I do not understand.

```
df = DataFrame(a = repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], outer=[2]),
           b = repeat([2, 1], outer=[4]),
           c = randn(8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to multiply column "b" by a "log"

Assuming you mean you want to apply the (natural) `log` to each element in column `:b`, you can do the following:

`log.(df.b)`

`log(x)` applies the (natural) log to an individual element `x`. By putting a dot after the log, you are [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions-1) the `log` function across each element.

If you wanted to replace column b, do the following:

`df.b = log.(df.b)`

> and then replace NaN by 0s

I'm assuming you want to handle the case where you have a `DomainError` (ie taking the `log` of a negative number). Your best best is to handle the error before it arises:

`map( x -> x <= 0 ? 0.0 : log(x), df.b)`

This maps the [anonymous function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions-1) `x -> x <= 0 ? 0.0 : log(x)` across each element of column b in your DataFrame. This function tests if `x` is less than zero - if yes then return `0.0` else return `log(x)`. This "one-line `if` statement" is called a [ternary operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-conditional-evaluation-1).

Answer (score 4):

Use a generator:

```
( v <= 0. ? 0. : log(v) for v in df.c )
```

If you want to add a new column:

```
df[!, :d] .= ( v <= 0. ? 0. : log(v) for v in df.c)
```

This is faster than using `map` (those tests assume that `df.d` already exits:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime $df[!, :d] .= ( v <= 0.0 ? 0.0 : log(v) for v in $df.c)
  1.440 μs (14 allocations: 720 bytes)

julia> @btime $df[!, :d] .= map( x -> x <= 0.0 ? 0.0 : log(x), $df.c);
  1.570 μs (14 allocations: 720 bytes)
```